# Printing out netmask

Tags: c, networking, ipv6

I have been writing a program that lists all of the IP addresses, netmasks, and interface names of my computer and I have run into a problem printing out the netmasks. The problem only seems to happen with IPv6. Here is the code:

```
int i;
struct ifaddrs *ifap, *ifa;


    getifaddrs(&ifap);
    char *net_mask = NULL; 
    int buffer_size = 200;
    char *ifa_addr = NULL;

    for (ifa = ifap; ifa; ifa = ifa->ifa_next)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in *ifan = (struct sockaddr_in *) ifa->ifa_netmask; //interface netmask
        struct sockaddr_in *ifaa_in = (struct sockaddr_in*)ifa->ifa_addr; //interface address

        //same as above with the exception that it is for ipv6
        struct sockaddr_in6 *ifan6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) ifa->ifa_netmask;
        struct sockaddr_in6 *ifaa_in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6*)ifa->ifa_addr;
        char *prevNet_mask = net_mask;
        net_mask = (char*)calloc(buffer_size, sizeof(char*));
        ifa_addr = (char*)calloc(buffer_size, sizeof(char*));

        inet_ntop(ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family,ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET?(void*)&ifan->sin_addr : (void*)&ifan6->sin6_addr, net_mask, buffer_size);
        inet_ntop(ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family, ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET?(void*)&ifaa_in->sin_addr: (void*)&ifaa_in6->sin6_addr ,ifa_addr , buffer_size);
        printf("Interface: %s\tNetMask: %s", ifa->ifa_name, net_mask);

        //space evenly
        int num_spaces = strlen(net_mask) - 40;
        if(num_spaces < 0) num_spaces *= -1;
        for(i = 0; i <num_spaces;i++) printf(" ");

        printf("Address: %s\n",ifa_addr);
    }
```

This is my output:

```
Interface: {BE3A9EA6-72AB-40FD-9036-9AC6BA4D75CF}       NetMask: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::                   Address: fe80::9cfb:3ebd:d866:e214
Interface: {BE3A9EA6-72AB-40FD-9036-9AC6BA4D75CF}       NetMask: 255.255.0.0                             Address: 169.254.226.20
Interface: {AA4D555F-C490-40DE-9F61-8E5AB3252389}       NetMask: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::                   Address: fe80::e994:389a:9ab4:1e45
Interface: {AA4D555F-C490-40DE-9F61-8E5AB3252389}       NetMask: 255.255.0.0                             Address: 169.254.30.69
Interface: {E1AE93D7-66CC-4651-A470-1445CC777F36}       NetMask: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::                   Address: fe80::5837:88eb:5801:273e
Interface: {E1AE93D7-66CC-4651-A470-1445CC777F36}       NetMask: 255.255.0.0                             Address: 169.254.39.62
Interface: {A251C284-7DC3-4F56-AB6A-8A4E4E218B6F}       NetMask: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff Address: 2602:306:8390:10f0::43
Interface: {A251C284-7DC3-4F56-AB6A-8A4E4E218B6F}       NetMask: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::                   Address: 2602:306:8390:10f0:6810:b0eb:1287:3138
Interface: {A251C284-7DC3-4F56-AB6A-8A4E4E218B6F}       NetMask: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff Address: 2602:306:8390:10f0:116d:50d0:4291:c8ab
Interface: {A251C284-7DC3-4F56-AB6A-8A4E4E218B6F}       NetMask: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::                   Address: fe80::6810:b0eb:1287:3138
Interface: {A251C284-7DC3-4F56-AB6A-8A4E4E218B6F}       NetMask: 255.255.255.0                           Address: 192.168.1.70
Interface: {D301A0B1-F567-11E5-A797-806E6F6E6963}       NetMask: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff Address: ::1
Interface: {D301A0B1-F567-11E5-A797-806E6F6E6963}       NetMask: 255.0.0.0                               Address: 127.0.0.1
Interface: {01CEB8B7-97FE-40AC-A5D4-47A61834A467}       NetMask: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff Address: fe80::5efe:c0a8:146
Interface: {4ED4A6C1-0496-4F0B-AD77-395C9F275D41}       NetMask: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::                   Address: 2001:0:9d38:90d7:2c9a:771:97c6:fef0
Interface: {4ED4A6C1-0496-4F0B-AD77-395C9F275D41}       NetMask: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::                   Address: fe80::2c9a:771:97c6:fef0
Interface: {A8CF5839-BA78-4C69-865E-3BE15F9F9A2C}       NetMask: 0.0.0.0                                 Address: 0.0.0.0
```

It seems that some interfaces have an incomplete ipv6 netmask. Can anyone shed some light as to why that is?

Comment: I don't see what is wrong. You basically have two IPv6 masks (IPv6  really only uses CIDR notation): `/64` and `/128`. Your `/64` masks are correct at `ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::`, and the `/128` masks are correct at `ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`. IPv6 will use those, and, maybe, `/127` for point-to-point links.

Comment: @RonMaupin I know this is a bit late but I feel this question does not deserve it's own post. With that said, Is there a way to an interface name that is not a bunch of random letters? For example the name of one of the interfaces on my computer is isatap.attlocal.net

Comment: You are referring to a DNS name.

Comment: @RonMaupin Really Because when I look up all of the interfaces on my computer using the terminal is says "Tunnel Adapter isatap.attlocal.net". The reason I say this is because I am trying to determine which interface is my Wireless LAN adapter.

Comment: Your OS is appending it DNS domain to whatever it decides to call its interface. What an interface is named is completely OS and, sometimes, user dependent. What you have for an interface name (isatap) can be changed by a user in some OSes (e.g. Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The netmasks are not incomplete, double colon means one or more consecutive blocks of zero.